# Issue related to function Wait()

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to set up a Toplist app to get hot topics on the Internet. The Github project is [here](https://github.com/tophubs/TopList). This project is built by Golang and Mysql.

The program tries to grab hot information from several pages at the same time. error shows `dial tcp: lookup tcp/port: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.` when I run the client app.

Note that I'm a newbie to golang and mysql, Please forgive me if I didn't describe this problem well. :)

I am on windows os. I open an issue about this error on the Github but have not been answered yet. The `getaddrinfow` seems to be a windows socket related function where I found in this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfow)

I debugged the code in Goland. I got error in this line:

error occurred in group.Wait()

```
    allData := []string{
        "V2EX",
        "ZhiHu",
        "WeiBo",
    }
    fmt.Println("starting catching" + strconv.Itoa(len(allData)) + "types of data")
    group.Add(len(allData))
    var spider Spider
    for _, value := range allData {
        fmt.Println("starting catching" + value)
        spider = Spider{DataType: value}
        go ExecGetData(spider)
    }
    group.Wait() //error occured in group.Wait()
    fmt.Print("completed catching")
}
```

Here is where the error had been thrown (in line 5).

```
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint64(statep, state, state+1) {
            if race.Enabled && w == 0 {
                race.Write(unsafe.Pointer(semap))
            }
            runtime_Semacquire(semap) // where error occured
            if *statep != 0 {
                panic("sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned")
```

Comment: The error looks like a network error, possible coming somewhere from `ExecGetData`. You see it in group.Wait() because that's where all the goroutines you created work. Try running the for loop without goroutines, call ExecGetData synchronously so you can see where the error is.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  Information that's missing: declaration of `group` and surrounding code, the definition of `ExecGetData`.